# vuejs 2 how to add child component without npm

Tags: vuejs2

I use vuejs2 and want to attach some component to my main one. Now I can have something like this:

```
var Component ={
    template: '<div>1</div>'
};
```

However, I want the thing in template to be a partial html from some other directory, like template:'../../com/a.html', I heard x-template but not know how to use it. Also, is there some lib other than webpack/browserify/npm series I can use directly just by add the script in the end of html?

Answer (score 0):

You have your template file as

```
/*  yourPath/name.template.html */

<div class="myClass">
    1
</div>
```

Then in the component file, you can do following:

```
export default {
    template: require('yourRelativePath/name.template.html'),
    data: function () {
        return {
        };
    }
}
```